# How can I best check to see if ANY string in a vector either is or is contained within a specific column of a matrix for EVERY matrix in a list?

Tags: r, function, apply, text-processing

I'm writing a little script in R to check if an email address has a valid domain extension.  I've read in and vectorized a file of the current valid extensions, e.g. com, uk, biz, etc.  Let's say for example:

```
valid_domain_extensions <- c('com', 'biz', 'de', 'uk')
```

Then I've got a list of matrices of 100,000 captured emails, which were intentionally written in an obfuscatory way, e.g. name [at] domain /dot/ biz.  The matrices are from a str_match_all regex pattern, with subgroups as columns.

(edited to add here:)

So the input would be a list of matrices that look like this:

```
           [,1]                  [,2]  [,3]    [,4]          [,5]  [,6]
[1] name at stackoverflow dot com name    at   stackoverflow   dot  com
```

What I want to do is check all 100,000 of the subgrouped columns (ie, all the [,6]s from my input list that captured the domain extensions to see if they are equal to, or at least have one of the strings from the domain extension vector, for validation.  And then spit out a canonicalized address.

Is there a more R-otic way to do it than my attempt here?  It works, but it seems kind of bulky and gross.

```
validationFunction <- function(x){

y <- x[,6]
z <- any((sapply(y, grepl, valid_domain_extensions))) # valid_domain_extensions is a long vector
if (z){
    return(paste(x[,2],'@', x[,4], '.', x[,6], sep = "", collapse = NULL))
} else {
    return("Invalid Email Address")
}

}

final_list_of_emails <- lapply(tokenized_rough_emails, validationFunction)

print(final_list_of_emails)
```

Thanks.

Comment: "R-otic", that's a new one to me!

Comment: Can you provide some sample input?

Comment: Sure.  I'll edit some in.

Comment: Seems fairly "R-otic" to me :) Only "improvement" I can think of woudl be that if you're using another function to create cols 2-6 and then using `validationFunction` for col6, you could skip the column creation altogether and use `regexec` with `regmatches` in `validationFunction` directly to get the extension and compare it to the list of acceptable extensins.